# Proof then $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\geq \left(\displaystyle\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3$

Tags: inequality

If $a,  b,  c$ are non-negative numbers, prove  then

> $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\geq \left(\displaystyle\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3$

$8a^3+8b^3+8c^3-24abc\geq\displaystyle(b^3+3b^2c+3bc^2+c^3-6a(b^2+2bc+c^2)+12a^2(b+c)-8a^3)$

$16a^3+7b^3+7c^3\geq 3b^2c+3bc^2-6ab^2+12abc-6ac^2+12a^2b+12a^2c$

$16a^3+7b^3+7c^3+6ab^2+6ac^2\geq 3b^2c+3bc^2+12abc+12a^2b+12a^2c$

$AM-GM$

$\frac{6a^3+6ab^2}{2}\geq 6\sqrt{a^4b^2}$

$6a^3+6ab^2\geq 12a^2b...(1)$

$\frac{6a^3+6ac^2}{2}\geq 6\sqrt{a^4c^2}$

$6a^3+6ac^2\geq 12a^2c...(2)$

$\frac{4a^3+4b^3+4c^3}{3}\geq 4^3\sqrt{a^3b^3c^3}$

$4a^3+4b^3+4c^3\geq 12abc...(3)$

$\frac{b^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\geq ^3\sqrt{b^6c^3}$

$2b^3+c^3\geq 3b^2c...(4)$

$\frac{b^3+c^3+c^3}{3}\geq ^3\sqrt{b^3c^6}$

$b^3+2c^3\geq 3bc^2...(5)$

$(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)$, we get

$16a^3+7b^3+7c^3+6ab^2+6ac^2\geq 3b^2c+3bc^2+12abc+12a^2b+12a^2c$

Proved.

Comment: Are you enunciating a theorem, or you have a question?

Comment: What have you tried? Does expanding out all of the terms help?

Comment: I am closing this post because it is not clear to me what the *question* is.  Can you please edit the post to clarify what you are looking for?  What kind of answer are you expecting?  Are you asking for a critique of your argument? or are you asking for a proof of an inequality?  which inequality?

Comment: i hope another method to solve this question

Comment: @XanderHenderson ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b+c<2a$ then $$LHS \geq 0 \ge RHS.$$
If $b+c \geq 2a.$ We write inequality as
$$4(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc) \geq (b+c-2a)^3,$$
or
$$4(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) \geq  (b+c-2a)^3.$$
Because $a+b+c = 3a+(b+c-2a) \geq b+c-2a,$ so we will show that
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\geq (b+c-2a)^2,$$
equivalent to
$$3(b-c)^2 \geq 0.$$
Which is true. Equality holds when $ a=b=c$ or $ a=0,\,b=c.$

**Note.** We have
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc-{2\left(\frac{b+c}{2}-a\right)^3}$$
$$=(b-c)^2+\frac{3\,a}{2} \Big[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\Big] \geq 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by 8 and expanding, we WTS

$$ 16 a^3   + 7 b^3  + 7 c^3 + 6 a b^2  + 6 a c^2 \geq 12 a^2 b + 12 a^2c + 12 abc + 3b^2 c + 3 bc^2. $$

This follows by taking AM-GM creatively with terms on the left, to get terms on the right.

Give it a try. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why it doesn't seem to work.

As an example, one of the inequalities we can use is:

> $ 6 a^3 + 6 ab^2 \geq 12 a^2 b $

Comment: Thanks,  i will try it

Comment: That i know is AM GM using for real positive number,  but the question say a,  b,  c is non-negative number.

Comment: @Kuhaku AMGM works for non-negative numbers, not just positive numbers. (If you disagree, then deal with the case of $a = 0, b = 0 , c = 0$ separately.)

Comment: Thanks,  for the correction

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin, i get it

Comment: @Kuhaku Great, that's the way I did it too!

Answer (score 1):

Since the $\text{LHS}$ is symmetric in $a,b,c$, and the $\text{RHS}$ can be written as
$$
\left(\frac{(a+b+c)-3a}{2}\right)^3
$$
it suffices to prove the inequality with the additional assumption $a\le b\le c$.

Replacing $b,c$ by $a+x,a+x+y\;$respectively (where $x,y\ge 0$), we get
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}
&=
\Bigl({\small{\frac{1}{8}}}\Bigr)
(
24ax^2+24axy+24ay^2+8x^3+12x^2y+18xy^2+7y^3
)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
all terms of which are nonnegative, thus proving the required inequality.